# Sci-fi based ‘game show’ similar to The Crystal Maze?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched a few episodes of a British show with my Dad once, where the contestants would take on the role of scavengers aboard a space ship hunting down clues or items or performing tasks. I forget the specifics. There may have been two teams. They were faced by either a group of an individual character who would try to stop them. This 'villain' was a cyborg and reminds me (thinking back) of the Borg. Oh, and every thing was red.

The finale of the show was something like a gauntlet and a paintball match mixed together. I saw the show in the early to mid-nineties, and I'd love to be able to track it down to watch again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Scavengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scavengers_%28game_show%29)?